# 192.com "superzoom" 4cm resolution aerial imagery

Tags: bing-maps

192.com used to have super high resolution aerial imagery (for London at least) .. but it seems to have disappeared. Now it just seems to be serving imagery from Bing.

Is there anywhere else this aerial imagery can be viewed?